# Webserver stops loading during long API call (never shows return)

Tags: php, python, apache, api, lamp

I am using a LAMP stack with a homegrown Python API. I send requests to do things on another server, and then return a response which my PHP parses and displays.

This usually works out perfectly, but I recently implemented a call that takes a long time to run, and on making the API call the webserver starts loading and after a while I can see it just gives up and stops loading (so effectively I stay on the same page, even though the api eventually successfully gets a response from the other server and returns)

Is this a timeout setting i can change? or how should I handle this

Comment: Is PHP making the call or being called? Can you confirm where the disconnect is happening?

Comment: php makes the call and gets a response back, which it then displays. its the result of a shell_exec on a python script

Comment: and on faster setups this issue does not occur